# Mysql database table column value increment not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So i made this database table called votes where i added 2 columns: likes and dislikes. 
In html i have 2 buttons: like button and dislike button.
When i press the like button i want to increment the likes column value by 1, but i seem to be doing it wrong.

PHP:

```
 if(isset($_POST['like'])) {

    $sql = 'UPDATE votes';  
    $sql .= 'SET likes = likes + 1';    
    $sql .= 'WHERE id = 1';

    // prepare
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    // execute
    $result = $stmt->execute();
 }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Like" name="like">
<input type="submit" value="Dislike" name="dislike"">
</form>
```

Comment: No space between votes and SET, and +1, and WHERE. Your expression is basically `UPDATE votesSET likes = likes + 1WHERE id = 1` - you can validate this by echoing `$sql`. Besides, such a short query can just be put in one line.

Comment: where is the error output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo, you are missing spaces between each row.

```
$sql = 'UPDATE votes ';  
$sql .= 'SET likes = likes + 1 ';    
$sql .= 'WHERE id = 1';
```